# Distance of a Point from Hyperbola

Tags: calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

Consider the part of hyperbola $H_{+}=\{(x,1/x)\colon x>0\}$ in the first quadrant, and $(a,b)$ any point in the plane (for sake of convenience, say $a,b>0$). If $(a,b)$ does not lie on the hyperbola $H_{+}$, how to determine

(1) The (minimum) distance of $(a,b)$ from $H_{+}$

(2) The point of $H_{+}$ which is closest to $(a,b)$.

I would like to determine these things algebraically as well as geometrically.

---

The way I proceeded is as follows: if $(y,1/y)$ is closest to $(a,b)$, then $y$ satisfies a fourth degree equation of the type $Y^3(Y-a)=(1-bY)$. But I couldn't proceed further.

Answer (score 3):

Let the curve $y=1/x$ be parametrized by $P(t)=(x,y)=(t,1/t).$ Then the squared distance from $(a,b)$ to $P(t)$ has derivative $(2/t^2)[t^4-at^3+bt-1],$ and so ignoring the $2/t^2$ factor the critical points are the roots of 
$$g(t)=t^4-at^3+bt-1,$$ just as stated in the posted question (with the letter $Y$ used for $t$).This would be a stopping point in general, except for numerical methods given specific $a,b,$ if one wants to avoid solving a general quartic equation.

An interesting (very) special case is that in which $a=b$ [call each $k$] with $(k,k)$ in quadrant I and lying say above the curve $y=1/x.$ Here loking at it geometrically we should expect the two points $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ on the full hyperbola to give critical points, so that $g(t)$ should factor leaving a quadratic. Indeed with $a=b=k$ we get to $g(t)=(t-1)(t+1)(t^2-kt+1).$ The quadratic here has no real roots when $k<2,$ while if $k=2$ it is $(t-1)^2$ making an order 3 zero for $g(t)$ at $t=1.$ What seems interesting (to me) is that when $k>2$ the two values of $t$ from the quadratic lead to two points on $y=1/x$ which win out over the point $(1,1)$ as being closer to it on the curve. The squared distance from $(k,k)$ to $(1,1)$ is $2(1-k)^2,$ while after some algebra the squared distance from either of the other two points (from the quadratic) is $k^2-2.$ And if one subtracts this from $2(1-k)^2$ the result is $(k-2)^2>0.$ [note we need $k \ge 2$ anyway for this expression to refer to a real difference of squared lengths in the situation of the problem]

Comment: We should arrive at a fourth degree equation (since, I heard about Bezout's theorem: two curves of degree two intersect at four points with some exceptions.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $(y,1/y) \in H_+$ be the point in $H_+$ closest to $(a,b)$.

The gradient of $H_+$ at $(y, 1/y)$ is given by $\frac{d}{dx}(1/x) = -\frac{1}{x^2}$.

So the tangent to $H_+$ at $(y,1/y)$ is the set $\{(y,1/y) + r(-1/y^2,1):r \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

This tangent is perpendicular to the straight line joining $(y,1/y)$ and $(a,b)$, so we have

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{c}
a-y\\
b-1/y\\
\end{array}
\right) \cdot \left(
\begin{array}{c}
-1/y^2\\
1\\
\end{array}
\right) = 0. $$

The positive solution to this quadratic is $y = \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$, so the closest point to $H_+$ is $\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}}\right)$, and this can be used to work out the shortest distance from $(a,b)$ to $H_+$.

Comment: I think it is really the fourth degree polynomial as OP has given it. How would this method work to get the distance say from $(3,3)$ to the hyperbola? From your formula the closest point would be $(1,1),$ which is at distance $\sqrt{8}$ from $(3,3),$ however there is a closer point at distance $\sqrt{7}$ namely $(c,1/c)$ where $c=(3+\sqrt{5})/2.$

Comment: If $H_{+}$ is parametrized as the pairs $(y,1/y)$ then the tangent vector at that point is $(1,-1/y^2)$ and it looks like for some reason you've reversed these coordinates above, which made the resulting equation come out only a quadratic. But if the dot product $(1,-1/y^2)$ with the segment (vector) $(a-y,b-1/y)$ is set it to zero then one arrives at the quartic $y^4-ay^3+by-1$ as in the post.

Comment: I have indeed reversed those co-ordinates. My apologies..

Answer (score 0):

To add onto solving @coffeemath's polynomial equality

$$x^4-ax^3+bx-1=0,$$ we begin by re-writing the polynomial as follows:

$$(x^2+Ax+B)^2=Cx^2+Dx+E.$$ Now expand and equate coefficients, adding the extra condition $D^2-4CE=0.$ Once done, take square roots,

$$x^2+Ax+B=\pm_1\sqrt{C}\left(x+\frac{D}{2C}\right)$$ and solve the quadratic.